# How come my section headers only disappear on larger devices?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

It works perfectly on phones with a width of 320 like iPhone 4 and 5. When I test on the simulator for the 6 and up however, the uitableview section headers are no longer visible for some reason. Here is the relevant code:

```
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 30))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.47, blue:0.45, alpha:1.00)

        let sectionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 30))
        switch section {
        case 0:
            sectionLabel.text = "Monday to Friday"
        case 1:
            sectionLabel.text = "Saturday"
        case 2:
            sectionLabel.text = "Sunday"
        default:
            sectionLabel.text = ""
        }

        sectionLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
        sectionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        sectionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
        headerView.addSubview(sectionLabel)

        return headerView
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> Float {
        return 30.0
    }
```

**BEFORE I tap on first tableview cell...**
[image: BEFORE I tap on first tableview cell]

**WHILE I tap on first tableview cell...**
[image]

**This is it working on iPhone 5...**
[image]

Comment: `tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int)` should return `CGFloat`. Aren't you getting an error cause you're returning `Float` for that?!

Comment: What do you mean Sam? It is returning float :P